# text_field with type :date doesn't get bound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-3

This date field:

```
<%= f.text_field :my_date, id: 'id-123', type: 'date' %>
```

doesn't get bound to the value of `my_date` of the model on the, for example, edit page. When I load the page, it's always "empty".

[image]

Why is that? I also tried:

```
<%= f.text_field :my_date, id: 'id-123', type: 'date', value: '11/11/11' %>
<%= f.text_field :my_date, id: 'id-123', type: 'date', value: '11-11-11' %>
```

and it also didn't work.

Comment: And your model is? Is ``:my_date`` an virtual attribute? What do you have in your form definition?

Comment: @dgilperez, it's a normal attribute like created_at.

Comment: @jawanam works perfectly in my form. Are you sure its not something in your model?

Comment: @Dimitry_N, no, and strong params can't be the cause because doesn't  even get bound when the page is loaded, not when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Dimitry_N, the value of my_date is "2014-03-03 00:00:00", can it be the cause?

Comment: @jawanam doubt it. I think it would, at least, raise an error. So when you leave the default input in the `:my_date` filed. Nothing happens, the field is just blank?

Comment: @Dimitry_N, yes, I've changed the type of the column in the db from date time to date but the input is still blank. Actually, when I load it at "edit" action and see the value using pry, it's "Mon, 03 Mar 2014". Maybe that's the cause? Why doesn't it display in the such a format?

Comment: @jawanam when you submit, what does it say in `params`?

Comment: @Dimitry_N, "my_date"=>"2015-02-03" And the html on "edit" is `<input  name="model123[my_date]" type="date" value="03.02.2015">` But still the input looks empty. I think I found the error, Chrome says " The specified value '03.02.2015' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'."

Comment: @Dimitry_N, no need, thanks. You can post your answer.

Comment: Should that be `f.date_field`?